# can anyone explain why we need ngModel and #nameField="ngModel" both in same input field of angular6 forms?

Tags: angular6, angular-forms

I am starting with my angular6 and I come across the syntax below.

```
<input type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="company-name"
    ngModel
    #nameField="ngModel"
    required
    minlength="3">
```

now my question is if `ngModel` and `name` is already there to uniquely identify form  component and `ngModel` directive to bind it with angular form why we need `#nameField="ngModel"`?

We can have input value from `name="company-name"`. so why 2 `NgModel`s?

and what is the difference between `#nameField="ngModel"` and `[(ngModel)]="nameField"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a valid template-driven form control - you only have to add `name="company-name"` and `ngModel`.

The template reference `#nameField="ngModel"` can be used as a variable in your html (so it's optional).

`[(ngModel)]="nameField"` is the two-way data binding in Angular, aka "banana-box" (for more detailed explanation read this article [two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) or the official documentation [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) )

Answer (score 0):

I always thought it is also needed for validation purposes so the error message show up nicely below the control.